# Windows Explorer keeps on restarting while accessing a specific folder

Tags: windows-7, windows

I've read some earlier questions too, but none of that gave any solution.

I have videos of approx 2.4GB in a folder.

Whenever I try to open that folder, Windows Explorer crashes. I don't have any backup to that videos so I can't delete them. Secondly, I can't even move them as whenever I click on that folder. The explorer crashes and restarts.

Things I've tried -

1. I've scanned my entire PC using AVG(licensed version)
2. Tried safe mode to backup them, same thing happens.

I'm using Windows 7 ultimate (32 bits)

Comment: Are they on your c: drive or another drive?  What happens if you use a command line to display the directory?  Try running chkdsk /f from an elevated command prompt (it will schedule it to run at the next boot).  It will take a while to complete and you don't want to interrupt it once it starts.

Comment: It's in D: drive. Performed chkdsk. This is the result - *Windows has checked the file system and found no problem*.

Comment: You ran chkdsk on D:?

Comment: What happens trying to open the directory with DOS commands in a command window?

Comment: @fixer1234 - I can access the folder, and also I play those videos using DOS. But when I try through GUI, Explorer crashes.

Comment: I would try sfc /scannow from an elevated command prompt.  That will check Windows Explorer for corruption.  One other thing to try off the top of my head.  Try it after a clean boot (http://www.thewindowsclub.com/what-is-clean-boot-state-in-windows), which will identify whether there is some third party software causing the problem.

Comment: @fixer1234 - ran chkdsk on both c: and d:.                                Ok I'll try that too, and will let u know.

Comment: @fixer1234 - I've tried this too, didn't resolved the problem. Secondly, I've disabled start up programs previously using tuneup utilities

Answer (score 0):

If Windows Explorer crashes in a video folder, you have a bad video codec installed. Use [AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) to disable 3rd party Video Codecs under the Tab `Codec`.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for replying this late, tried this too, Still facing the issue.

When I copied those videos the Explorer worked fine for days, but suddenly it started behaving this way.

Comment: have you disabled some codecs? You can also try to generate dumps of the Explorer crash: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx